# We need to merge two seperate TFS default collections into one TFS2012 into TFS2017

Tags: tfs

We have an aging TFS 2012 setup with two collections the default and another we can call collection2. We want to migrate them to an existing TFS 2017 instance that also has those same two named collections but within the collections are different projects.  We want to merge the two default collections into the 2017 default collection. And then most like do the same with the collection2.

I have seen references to a "TFS Integration Platform" that was said to do this, however it seems to be deprecated and unavailable.  ## as anybody been down this road before that can offer assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### You're in a bad spot.

You can easily attach the 2012 collections to the 2017 instance using a detach/ attach migration, but that won't merge things.

You can use a bunch of tools to migrate multiple things and is all depends on what it is you need to migrate.

For work items & test cases:

- [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools)
- Alternatively use [OpsHub Migration Tool](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) (paid)

TFVC:

- [Use the TFVC import tool in TFS to migrate the data into a Git Repository.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- Alternatively use [OpsHub Migration Tool](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) (paid)

Builds:

- n/a

Test Results:

- Use [OpsHub Migration Tool](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) (paid)

### A simpler solution

Do what's called a tip-migration and keep the old collections around for history purpose.